# Colorscheme in Vim not correct colors

Tags: vim

I downloaded this colorscheme here
https://vimcolors.com/1199/pulumi/dark

But this is what my Vim ends up looking like after applying it. I know it is definitely being applied because my colors changed after adding the line

```
colorscheme pulumi
```

in my .vimrc file but the colors match nothing like the actual colorscheme in the link.

**Image of my vim editor**

[image]

Here is my .vimrc file

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

"***************************************************** Plugins ***********************************************************
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim' "plugin manager is Vundle
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim' "plugin lightline for customizing status line 
set laststatus=2        "necessary for plugin lightline to work
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
"************************************************************************************************************************


"************************************************** Other Stylings ********************************************************
set number "display line numbers
colorscheme pulumi "vim colorscheme
```

Comment: What terminal are you using?  On what OS and version?  What does `echo $TERM` at the command line say?  Are you using a terminal multiplexor such as screen or tmux?

Comment: My Xterm is xterm-256color. My gnome version is GNOME Shell 3.25.4 and the terminal I'm using is the GNOME Terminal version 3.22.1.

Answer (score 1):

That color scheme contains two sets of colors: colors for a true color display, which are set as the GUI colors, and colors for a 256-color display.  In your case, you're using a terminal and don't have `termguicolors` set, so you're using the 256-color set, which will look different than the true color set.

With a new enough Vim, you can set the `termguicolors` option to use true colors in your terminal and have things look like they do in the GUI.  That would look like this:

```
if has("termguicolors")
  set termguicolors
  if &t_8f == ''
    " The first characters after the equals sign are literal escape characters.
    set t_8f=[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum
    set t_8b=[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum
  endif
endif
```

Note that you can also make it conditional on the value of the `$TERM` or `$COLORTERM` environment if you'd like.

Comment: So am I suppose to paste this in my vimrc file? I did and it is still not showing the right colors.

Comment: Yes, it goes in your `.vimrc` file.  You will need to literally insert an Escape character right before the `[`.  I included it but it got stripped out.

Comment: I added the escape character but still no luck.

Comment: What version of Vim are you using?

Comment: version 7 i believe. I just installed 8 today and it's still the same

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than that.  Try running `vim --version` and getting the full version number (e.g., 8.2) and the patches applied.  Also, in Vim, try running `:echo has("termguicolors")`.

Comment: version --> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct  6 2020 16:27:50)
Included patches: 1-1807
echo has("termguicolors") = 1

Comment: Some colorschemes seem to force bg & fg colors, overriding the effect of bk2204's code above.   Try `:colorscheme default` and see what happens.